# Django STATIC_URL always points to local directory

Tags: python, django, nginx, static

I want to serve the static content generated by django in a different host with nginx.
The server with the files has the name 'static-server' and I can't access it with django.

The static file looks like this:

```py
STATIC_URL = 'http://static-server/static/'
```

But the error log gives the following path:

```
"GET /http:/static-server/static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 500 145
```

Why is django looking for the files in local? How can I avoid this?

Comment: You don't put the complete URL including the domain, you just specify the /static/ part

Comment: How can I specify the host then?

Comment: You don't have to, django will simply append /static/ to your domain to serve static files, but make sure you have added static path to your Root URL conf urls.py
Follow this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: Hmm, that's not the point. I generated the static in "/opt/static" and then copy that content to another host in "/django/static". Then, in the nginx config rooted the "/static" path to "/django/static". Thing is, django can't find the other host.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, STATIC_URL cannot point to remote directories without the use of extra plugins.

If you want to serve static content generated by Django with another web server (ie: Nginx) it must be in the same host.